# bash: cd: /sda5: No such file or directory

Tags: command-line, split

I have files in `sda5` drive but when i tried to navigate into it, it gives me below error:

```
~$ cd /media
/media$ cd /sda5
bash: cd: /sda5: No such file or directory
/media$ ls
003C-91E4         2A88A65788A620F5_  70866F8C866F51A0_   Document   P
2A88A65788A620F5  70866F8C866F51A0   70866F8C866F51A0__  Document_  sus hill
```

I have a file to split (10GB in size).which is in drive Document.

Comment: Your title does not match your topic.

Comment: Do you understand that you should mount the filesystem before getting access?

Answer (score 1):

Drop the / in front of /sda5.

The / means the directory is searched from the root of your disc and you want `/media/sda5`.

Either do ...

- `cd /media` and then `cd sda5`

or

`cd /media/sda5`

Hit the tab after the `me` and it will auto complete it for you.

===

Regarding the edit.

- sda5 is -not- a directory but a mount point.
- One of these:

  ```
  003C-91E4         2A88A65788A620F5_  70866F8C866F51A0_   Document   P
  2A88A65788A620F5  70866F8C866F51A0   70866F8C866F51A0__  Document_  sus hill
  ```

  is sda5. So you need to do `cd /media/003C-91E4/` to access `3C-91E4`. With `ls` you can see contents of that disc. Type `mount` to get a list of mount points and their name.

Comment: sushil@sushil-Inspiron-N5110:~$ cd /home/media/sda5
bash: cd: /home/media/sda5: No such file or directory

Comment: it just say no such file or directory

Comment: @SusHill Where do you see in the answer `cd /home...`? The answer is good. Please read some basics about linux directory structure: thegeekstuff.com/2010/09/linux-file-system-structure

Comment: @Rinzwind i have edited my question? my drive is mount too...

Answer (score 0):

`/media` is seperate folder where you'll find it when you `cd` to `/` (root).. and is it always a best practice to use `pwd` and `ls` command whenever you're into a directory. These will keep you updated with what dir are you in currently (using `pwd`) and what are the dir reside within the current dir (using `ls`). BTW as **Rinzwind** said you're trying to jump to directory starts from root. I guess you're trying to mount a HDD or any storage device.. isn't it??

Comment: I did not follow you.. Can you be more descriptive please.